# Please Recommend Pure Land / Other Power Buddhism Books

Tags: books, pure-land, nembutsu

I have gradually become a Pure Land Buddhist. I chant as I cycle. But I would also like to read, in English or Japanese. Recently I read the book below (Not generally available I am afraid) and it made me feel good. Please would members recommend some other power Buddhism books.

別府信空上人（2015）『現物者の喜び』法然寺

Comment: Have you read the Pure Land sutras already?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you would like some academic literature but here goes:

[T’an-luan’s Theory of Two Kinds of Dharma-body as Found in Shinran’s Wago Writings](https://web.archive.org/web/20100707052207/http://www.shin-ibs.edu/documents/pwj3-2/05YY2.pdf) has a detailed description and great diagrams on this topic.[image]

[The Dawn of Chinese Pure Land Buddhist Doctrine: Ching-ying Hui-yuan's Commentary on the Visualization Sutra](https://www.amazon.com/gp/search?index=books&linkCode=qs&keywords=9780791402979)

Answer (score 1):

[The Promise of Amida Buddha: Honen's Path to Bliss](http://www.wisdompubs.org/book/promise-amida-buddha)

It is a collection of Honen's teachings and writings if you are interested in a Japanese Pure Land Buddhism and what later become Shin (True) Pure Land Buddhism via his disciple, Shinran.